# create a service which run the program during the launch of windows in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a program that needs to be started during the launch of Windows(before user login). I found an article, they said that I should create a service, but do not know how to generate service which runs the program on Windows Startup.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ideally the service would be the program, not a launcher.

Comment: Or you can schedule that program to run on `Start Up` using `Task Scheduler`

Comment: Since your program is graphical you should have your installer add it to the windows startup folder or the Run or RunEx registry hives. Alternatively, you could just let the user run it when they need it. It will be impossible (or reassuringly difficult) for a service to talk directly to the user console.

Comment: I used Reg but does not work

Comment: I used registry but does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clarification: WPF is a UI tool, and should **not** be implemented via a service. It is not supported in this usage. You should just use the `Run` key in windows: http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html

---

If you really want a service: Visual Studio has a "Windows Service" template; New Project => Templates => Visual C# => Windows Desktop => Windows Service. Use it.

Note: you will need to *install* the service too, and ensure the startup mode is set to "automatic"; there are three ways to do that:

- an installer project
- [`installutil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- or you can make the exe self-installing/un-installing by referencing the setup assemblies from inside the project and invoking the installar from code (I tend to use `my.exe -i` and `my.exe -u` to install/uninstall)

Comment: I do not have Windows Desktop => Windows Service.

Comment: I have created a program on WPF, C #. how can I run this program and run this program must make himself not the user

Comment: @QutfulloOchilov WPF is a UI app; services should **not ever** run a UI - and IIRC this isn't even supported in the last few versions of windows. If you want to run a UI app at startup, that has nothing whatsoever to do with a service - and should simply be done via the supported Windows "run this at startup" hooks; for example : http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/oreilly/windows/ron/startup_0401.html

Comment: I would like to start my app before user login.

Comment: @QutfulloOchilov you cannot start a UI application before login. Your requirement is meaningless. What is it that you actually want to do? What is the purpose of this app? For example, it might be valid to have a service (at system startup) *and* a UI app (in user space) that talks to the service